# I installed a Facebook Pixel to my new website and I notice there are other domains to my site. What are they?

Tags: dns, hosting

I have a simple landing page for insurance leads I setup a few days ago. After installing the Pixel I notice there are two other websites for the site somehow. The site is installed on a brand new Digital Ocean droplet.

I don't know anything about these sites. When I type the names of the sites in a browser they take me to my landing page.

I don't want to share any names of the site because I don't want you all registering visits with the pixel, so maybe I can give you site in a DM if you need to visit it. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DO, like any other cloud provider, re-use IP all the time. Most likely at one point, someone bought a domain and point it to their DO instance, then either forgot or don't bother to update the domain when they delete their instance (which release the IP back to the pool). This is a very common occurrence. One could also point a domain they bought to any IP they want, even those they don't own.

Your webserver right now is set to serve any request to 80/443 regardless of the domain. Fix that, and typing those URLs won't load your landing page. If you enabled HTTPS redirection, those URLs won't (automatically) load either, because the certificate won't match.